# MacOS Postgres in docker is not getting deleted after running docker-compose down

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am spinning up a Postgres database in Docker-compose and it worked great the first time.  I wanted to test some things so I ran

```
docker-compose down
```

And after my changes.  I ran `docker-compose up`.  This time, I keep getting a message saying

`PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization`

My docker-compose is as follows:

```
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:14.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${BP_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./admin/${BP_ENV:-dev}/database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=on -c log_rotation_age=1d -c log_directory=/mnt/log -c 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

I ran `docker-compose down --volumes` to try to get rid of everything, but it did not work.
Then, I deleted the entire `./data/postgres` folder on my local drive but it still failed.  After, I commented out `- ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data` but it still did not work.

How do I get rid of the existing database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `docker-compose down --volumes` will only delete Docker volumes. You're not using volumes; you're using bind-mounts, in which you are mounting a host directory inside your container:

```
    volumes:
      - ./admin/${BP_ENV:-dev}/database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

The way you delete that data is by using `rm`, as in:

```
rm -rf ./data/postgres/*
```

If you wanted to use a Docker volume for the database directory, that would look like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:14.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${BP_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./admin/${BP_ENV:-dev}/database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=on -c log_rotation_age=1d -c log_directory=/mnt/log -c 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

In this case, running `docker-compose down -v` (or `--volumes`, if you
prefer) would delete the database volumes.

Comment: Thanks for the information larsks!  In my case, it was actually caused by someone else changing some files and it caused the postgres database to spin up pre-maturely.  After it is spun up, the init.sh file is omitted.  Never the less that is great information!